# Are java imports used professionally?

Tags: java, class, import

I'm currently self studying Java, and am not sure with this "import" thing. It adds classes(not sure), and has methods that would serve a different function relative on the type of class I declare from the "import"ed thing.

I'm curious if import is frequently used for work, or is this relative to the user if he/she would want to use import or not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ThisObject = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's about as common as breathing.

Comment: Yes they are used professionally, and what's more they are used in whatever form the IDE provides them in, rather than by hand.

Comment: There isn't a professional Java developer on the planet that doesn't use imports extensively... Starting a variable with a capital letter, however, is **not** a common, standard practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java `import` is a **compile** time feature that allows you to omit the package name when programming. There is no byte-code `import`, the compiler will replace

```
Scanner ThisObject = new Scanner(System.in);
```

with

```
java.util.Scanner ThisObject = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

As for how common it is, I would say ***extremely***. However, there is another form of `import` called `static import` which allows you to bring `static` methods and fields from another class into your current *namespace*. `static import` is not very **common**. Finally, Java variable names start with a lower case letter (by convention).

```
import static java.lang.System.in;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner thisObject = new Scanner(in); // System.in through static import
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So from what I understood - imports are packages that could be called by other packages to their namespace, for the use of their classes/methods. I have not yet encountered static import yet, but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No. Packages organize classes into a tree. An import simply allows you to refer to a class name more concisely as you program. Packages aren't called by other packages; nor does importing change a package.